# Animating a custom QGraphicsItem with QPropretyAnimation

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyside

I want to make a car follow a path, so I tried animating a custom QGraphicsItem (describing a 'car') using QPropreties, starting by an example given on PySide documentation :

```
  self.anim = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.car, "geometry")
  self.anim.setDuration(4000);
  self.anim.setStartValue(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 100, 30));
  self.anim.setEndValue(QtCore.QRect(250, 250, 100, 30));
  self.anim.start();
```

`self.car` here is an instance of Car, a class that inherits from `QGraphicsItem` and `QObject` ( ***EDIT*** Changed this, see `EDIT 2`):

```
class Car(QtGui.QGraphicsItem, QtCore.QObject):

        def __init__(self, map = None, ....):

            super(Car, self).__init__()
            self.map = map
                    ....
```

I always get the same error code when executing this :

```
  QPropertyAnimation::updateState (geometry): Changing state of an animation without target
```

This is weird as the target is really set ! I tried putting setTargetObject ( see the [documentation on PySide](https://deptinfo-ensip.univ-poitiers.fr/ENS/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QPropertyAnimation.html#PySide.QtCore.PySide.QtCore.QPropertyAnimation.propertyName) ) but it didn't change anything.

Any idea about where that could come from ?

***EDIT :*** Something that could help -> I tried putting those three lines and the result shows that the object is not taken into account :

```
  print self.car
  self.anim.setTargetObject(self.car)
  print self.anim.targetObject()
```

Result

```
<engine.Car(this = 0x43f9200 , parent = 0x0 , pos = QPointF(0, 0) , z = 0 , flags =  ( ItemIsMovable | ItemIsSelectable ) )  at 0x1de0368>
None
```

***EDIT 2 :*** Changing the class inheritance to `QGraphicsObject` seems to have solved the 'no target' problem ! But I have a different error now (using a custom defined property 'pos'):

```
  QPropertyAnimation::updateState (pos, Car, ): starting an animation without end value
```

I defined my property that way :

```
def setPos(self, pos):
    self.x = pos[0]
    self.y = pos[1]
    self.update()

def readPos(self):
    return (self.x, self.y)

pp = QtCore.Property('tuple', readPos, setPos)
```

Comment: `QGraphicsItem` doesn't have a geometry attribute. You probably either want to animate the `boundingRect` (which I don't believe is possible), or some other property that you create yourself which controls how big you paint the car.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to first change the inheritance from `QGraphicsItem` and `QObject` to `QGraphicsObject`. Then, the second error I did is I didn't define my property (x and y) correctly.

I ended up re-implementing my class to use `QGraphicsObject`'s "`pos`" property and give it the correct start and end value (tuples).

Comment: Do you know why inheriting from QGraphicsItem and QObject was bad? What was wrong with definition of property. I stumbled across the same error and wish to solve it.

Comment: Actually QGraphicsObject is just QGraphicsItem + some signals and properties. (as it already inherits from QObject and defines the correct properties for rotation, position and such). From the Qt documentation: "The QGraphicsObject class provides a base class for all graphics items that require signals, slots and properties."

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to animate position, you can animate `GraphicsItem.pos` rather than defining your own position functions (unless you want the car to have a position within the `QGraphicsItem` itself.

As for `'starting an animation without end value'`, make sure you:

1. Call `setEndValue` on the animation.
2. Pass in the correct type to `setEndValue` (e.g. your current implementation would require a tuple, using `GraphicsItem.pos` would require a `QPoint`).

Comment: Thanks, while trying to get this fixed I noticed there's already a "pos" property in all GraphicsItem (and hence GraphicsObject).

I reimplemented my class using the native position attribute, and it's finally animated ! (unfortunately the animations is weird, there's an offset on the position values ... but I must have messed something up when reimplementing my class). Thanks !